# Find all the decomposition of a number using only odd numbers and up to N numbers max

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

I want to find all the decompositions of a number using only odd numbers and up to N numbers max.

For example for the number 7 and N = 3, I can only get 1+1+5, 1+3+3, 7. I can't get 1+1+1+1+3 because it's greater then N.

They hint us to use backtracking.

I strated writing the code and I am stuck. If someone can explian to me how to solve this problem it will be great.

```
int T(int n, int k)
{
    if (k == 0) 
    {
        return;
    }

    int arr[N];
    int f;
    for (f = 0; f < N; f++)
    {
        arr[f] = 0;
    }
    int sum = 0;
    int j = 1;
    int i = 1;
    int c = 0;

    while (j < k) {
        sum = sum + i;
        arr[c] = i;
        
        if (sum == n)
        {
            for (f = 0; f < N; f++)
            {
                if (arr[f] != 0)
                {
                    printf("%d ", arr[f]);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        else if (sum > n)
        {
            arr[c] = 0;
            sum = sum - i;
            i = i - 2;
        }
        else 
        {
            i = i + 2;
            j++;
            c++;
        }
    }
    T(n, k - 1);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Where are you stuck exactly? What is your strategy here?

Comment: @ggorlen I suming up the odd numbers starting from 1 until its equls to this number and print the numbers from the array. I also check if its pass the number, if the sum pass it I delete the last number I add and add the previus number and continue like this. I stuck because i thught cheking if there is a solution for N and to print the solution if there is one and then checkign again but this time for N-1.

Comment: if you insert `int N=k;`, change to `int j = 0;`  insert a `break` after `printf("\n");` and remove `T(n, k - 1);` you'll get a correct result  for `T(7,3);`.

Comment: Yes but I need to find all the other decomposition. for T(7,3) I need to get also 1+1+5 and 7. @Holger

Comment: One tip : If you have an odd number k you have : N(max c components) = k + decomposition(N-k, Max (c-1) components )

Comment: I found a solution how to solve the problem but its with even and odd numbers and there is no limit on the amount of connected numbers. I my problem I need to use only odd numbers and limit the amount of connected numbers to N. 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-all-unique-partitions-of-an-integer-set-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please compile with warnings (`-Wall`) and fix all of them (`-Werror` helps make sure you do this). I didn't build your code, but `int T(int n, int k)` says it returns an `int`, yet the function code is void.

With backtracking, you can't print at each node because the current node in the graph might not actually lead to a solution. It's premature to commit anything to the result set until you actually reach it.

It's best [not to print in functions that perform logical tasks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) anyway, but it can make the coding easier while developing the logic so I'll stick wiith it.

The backtracking suggestion is a good one. Here's the logic:

The "found result" base case is when `n == 0 && k >= 0`, if you're decrementing `n` and `k` and using them to represent the remaining value to reach the goal and the number of choices left. If you're incrementing variables to count up to `n` and `k`, that's fine too, in which case the base case is `current_total == n && taken_so_far <= k`.

Next, the "failure" base case is `k < 0 || n < 0` because we've either overshot `n` or run out of numbers to take.

After that, the recursive case is, in English, "try taking each odd number `i` up to `n`, recursing on the possibility that `i` might be part of the solution". Per your spec, we don't accept any sequence of descending numbers which prunes the recursion tree a bit.

Here's the code; again, returning a result is an exercise. I'm using a `k`-sized array to store potential results, then dumping it to stdout only when a result was found.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void odd_decomposition_search(
    int n, const int k, int taken_length, int *taken
) {
    if (n == 0 && taken_length <= k && taken_length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < taken_length - 1; i++) {
            printf("%d+", taken[i]);
        }

        printf("%d\n", taken[taken_length-1]);
    }
    else if (n > 0 && taken_length < k) {
        int i = taken_length ? taken[taken_length-1] : 1;

        for (; i <= n; i += 2) {
            taken[taken_length] = i;
            odd_decomposition_search(n - i, k, taken_length + 1, taken);
        }
    }
}

void odd_decomposition(const int n, const int k) {
    if (n <= 0 || k <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    int taken[k];
    odd_decomposition_search(n, k, 0, taken);
}

int main() {
    int n = 7;
    int k = 3;
    odd_decomposition(n, k);
    return 0;
}
```

If you're having trouble understanding the call stack, here's a visualizer you can run in the browser:

```js
const oddDecomp = (n, k, taken=[]) => {
  console.log("  ".repeat(taken.length), `[${taken}]`);

  if (n === 0 && taken.length <= k && taken.length) {
    console.log("  ".repeat(taken.length), "-> found result:", taken.join("+"));
  }
  else if (n > 0 && taken.length < k) {
    for (let i = taken.length ? taken[taken.length-1] : 1; i <= n; i += 2) {
      taken.push(i);
      oddDecomp(n - i, k, taken);
      taken.pop(i);
    }
  }
};

oddDecomp(7, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks! that explanation really made this subject 
clear for me, I was able to solve the next question by my self.